# WillCascadeOnDelete not working C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am not sure why the FileList is not being deleted when I delete Job.
It remains orphaned in the database.

Using Entity Framework 6.0.0.0.
Code First

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.FileList)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(j => j.FileListGuid)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

[Table("Job")]
internal class Job : BaseEntity, IDeletable, IFileList
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FileList")]
    public Guid? FileListGuid { get; set; }

    public virtual FileList FileList { get; set; }
}

[Table("FileList")]
class FileList : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Cascaded delete is always from parent (FileList) to child (Job).

Comment: @GertArnold - I am looking for cascade delete from parent (Job) to child (FileList).